# Dynamic Id on $Action.Account.View

Tags: javascript, id, urlfor

I try to do something like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var id = myObject.customId__c;
    var myLink = '<apex:outputLink value="{!URLFOR($Action.Contact.View, id)}">Test</apex:outputLink>';
</script>
```

This doesn't work !

But I don't know how I can put the id in the !URLFOR expression.
What is the correct syntax to add the id without call the Controller but only in Javascript ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to go to the detail page for that Contact record, then this should work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var id = myObject.customId__c;
    var myLink = '<apex:outputLink value="/"+id>Test</apex:outputLink>'; 
</script>
```

Comment: Ok it's work. I didn't know that I only needed Id. Thank you.